# Problema com apresentação de conteudo HTML utilizando this.props.children com ngReact

Tags: angularjs, react

Estou tentando apresentar o conteúdo que injeto dentro de uma diretiva Angular dentro de um componente React.

Veja abaixo a chamada para o componente:

```
<alert type="'danger'">
    <strong>Alert</strong>
    Voluptatem facilis magnam, optio provident eaque earum.
</alert>
```

Veja abaixo meu componente Angular/React:

```
const ALERT_TYPES = [
    'danger',
    'error', // alias for danger
    'info',
    'primary',
    'success',
    'warning'
];

angular
    .module('app')
    .value('Alert', React.createClass({
        displayName: 'Alert',
        propTypes: {
            children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
            className: React.PropTypes.string,
            type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(ALERT_TYPES).isRequired
        },
        render() {
            var componentClass = classNames(
                'Alert',
                'Alert--' + this.props.type,
                this.props.className
            );

            return (
                <section className={componentClass}>{this.props.children}</section>
            );
        }
    }))
    .directive('alert', alert);

function alert(reactDirective) {
    return reactDirective('Alert');
}
```

Infelizmente `this.props.children` retorna `undefined`. Alguem tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentado [nessa issue](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact/issues/128#issuecomment-165206724), isso não funciona, é precisa adicionar o `children` do lado do React.js, para que seja possível reescrever o componente. Veja abaixo o exemplo informado na issue:

```
let Alert = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Alert',
  propTypes: {
    heading: React.PropTypes.string,
    text: React.PropTypes.string,
    className: React.PropTypes.string,
    type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(ALERT_TYPES).isRequired
  },
  render() {
    let componentClass = classNames(
      'Alert',
      'Alert--' + this.props.type,
      this.props.className
    );

    return (
      <section className={componentClass}>
         <strong>{this.props.heading}</strong>
         {this.props.text}
       </section>
    );
  }
});
```

A chamada do Angular.js ficaria assim:

```
<alert type="'danger'" heading="Alert" text="Voluptatem facilis magnam, optio provident eaque earum."/>
```